# Python's Lmfit package not converging to a meaningful result

Tags: python, python-3.x, curve-fitting, lmfit

I'm running the code below:

```
import numpy as np
from lmfit import Model

def exp_model(x, ampl1=1.0, tau1=0.1):             
    exponential = ampl1*np.exp(-x/tau1)
    return exponential

x = np.array([2.496,2.528,2.56,2.592,2.624])
y = np.array([8774.52,8361.68,7923.42,7502.43,7144.11])

dec_model = Model(exp_model, nan_policy='propagate')
results = dec_model.fit(y, x=x, ampl1=y[0])

results.plot()
```

The result I get is

[image]

which means that the fit is just failing for some reason. I can't figure out why. It had worked for similar data before. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wasn't converging because the initial value for the tau1 parameter was too far away from the real value. The code below works well.

```
import numpy as np
from lmfit import Model

def exp_model(x, ampl1=1.0, tau1=1.0): # The initial value of tau1 was changed from 0.1 to 1.0            
    exponential = ampl1*np.exp(-x/tau1)
    return exponential

x = np.array([2.496,2.528,2.56,2.592,2.624])
y = np.array([8774.52,8361.68,7923.42,7502.43,7144.11])

dec_model = Model(exp_model, nan_policy='propagate')
results = dec_model.fit(y, x=x, ampl1=y[0])

results.plot()
```

[image]